# Vue: Nested Conditional Templates, they work but is it best practice?

Tags: vue.js

I tried to search and scraped al documentation without success.
I'm new to vue.js but not to JS. As a tutorial to learn I'm converting some old piece of codes of mine from vanilla/jquery to vue.js. The challenge I'm facing now is with nested conditional templates.

I have this basic form and I want to show some part of it only if some conditions are met. The first solution I found was to nest Conditional Templates and it actually works like a charm, but I was wondering if I'm doing it the right way.

I removed all unnecessary things from the snippet (Bootstrap, ...)

Any suggestions from tenured Vue devs?
Thanks a lot

```js
    var form_one = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            errors: [],
            type: "default",
            mainFormToggle: null,
            wasMeeting: "default",
        },
        methods: {
            preCheck: function (e) {
                this.errors = []; // removes any errors eventually shown in the page

                if (this.type) {
                    this.mainFormToggle = true;
                }
                if (!this.type) {
                    this.errors.push('Please select a course type!');
                    this.mainFormToggle = false;
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

```html
<div id="app">
    <select class="form-control" id="type" v-model="type" @change="preCheck()" name="type">
        <option value="default" disabled selected>Choose the correct type to be initiated</option>
        <option value="one">one</option>
        <option value="two">two</option>
    </select>

    <!-- FIRST CONDITIONAL "ROOT" TEMPLATE -->
    <template id="form-two" v-if="mainFormToggle">
        <div><label for="firstName">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="firstName" v-model="firstName"></div>

        <!-- FISRT NESTED CONDITIONAL TEMPLATE -->
        <template v-if="type === 'one'">
            <div> <label for="wasMeeting">Was a meeting held?</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="wasMeeting" v-model="wasMeeting">
                    <option value="default" disabled selected>Choose an option</option>
                    <option value="y">Yes</option>
                    <option vlaue="n">No</option>
                </select></div>

            <!-- SECOND CONDITIONAL NESTED TEMPLATE -->
            <template v-if="wasMeeting === 'y'">
                <div> <label for="meeting-by-who">By which teacher was the Meeting held?</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control form-control-sm" id="meeting-by-who" placeholder=""
                        rows="5"></textarea></div>
            </template>
        </template>
    </template>
</div>
```

Comment: I used similar tactics to handle form branching or optional form fields.  I would point you in the direction of considering where your data ends up.  If it is sent to the back-end to be process with PHP or other server side then it might be expecting fields that aren't there.  This could be solved by switching your v-if statements with v-show, but there are other things to consider with this approach: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if-vs-v-show

Comment: Thanks, Dean! Yeah, data will be sent to a PHP backend to be processed and stored into a DB, I collect and send a stringified JSON object so if some values will be `null` it's not a big deal, the server-side logic will then exclude them. My concern here is mostly on front-end since I don't use _components_ but just a single Vue instance. Also, this HTML Vue syntax is new and quite weird to me...I'm learning a lot and it started to make a lot of sense now but at the beginning I just thought WTF is this spaghetti mix of HTML and js? At least now I know I am not alone to nest templates

Comment: Mauro, I might also mention as you bind your values that you put all your form fields into a single object. This is a choice, but if you are doing custom form processing, it can be a nice step to stringify later.  For example, v-model="form.wasMeeting".  I'm not an advanced Vue user with multiple components, but here is a recent branching form app I've been working on https://github.com/josdea/coursebuilder